# How to do Facebook places search without user facebook authorize

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am still new to Facebook Graph API, and trying to start using facebook places search. (search places by location)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000
```

One thing i have noticed is user have to login to their Facebook account to do the search, otherwise the search will be rejected.

Could anyone shine me some light pointing a direction to work around this?
Any links or articles will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately I think this is a design flaw (or feature?). By this design, only Facebook authentication users can search for places. Others cannot. It seems more like a capability designed to serve end users than actual apps.

The flaw I see is that many applications out there are trying to offer optional Facebook integration but don't make it obligatory. Unfortunately, as it stands now, the places API can't be used as a service for apps just additional functionality for FB users.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible. Per the error message: "An access token is required to request this resource." Most of the graph api requires an authenticated user (ie an access token) to make requests. There are only a few calls that can be made without the access token and this is not one of them.

Comment: Yep that is what i thought, just wondering why they are not opening it up

Comment: I think that they just want to ensure the system is not abused by random sites using the service without authenticating. Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer. :)